# Why LSPosed slows down screenshot take?

Tags: android-10, magisk, screenshots, samsung-one-ui, lsposed

My phone is Samsung Galaxy M20 (OneUI 2.0 - Android 10) and I use the latest Magisk v24.3 (24300). After installing LSPosed, my phone takes screenshots more slowly.

Why? Is possible to fix this? If possible, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LSPosed uses Zygisk or Riru for injection interface.

There is no solution for Riru because if your LSPosed is using Riru, update Magisk to the latest version. Enable Zygisk (Beta) feature in Magisk Manager. Then download the Zygisk version of LSPosed from the GitHub repo, and install it.

Main Solution:

1. Enable DenyList in 'Magisk Manager > Settings'
2. Select SystemUI with its subprocesses.

This operation will revert all Magisk modifications for SystemUI and the problem will be solved!